# web application Login Page without using a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-applications

I have an small web application in a local web server that needs a login page, this application will be used only in one computer locally and just needs to have around 10 accounts. I do not see the need to have a Database. I know there is a way to store usernames and password on the web.config file but I need to be able to change usernames and password dynamically once logged in in the application. What methods can I use to do this besides using cookies? Can I store the usernames and password in an XML file or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [authorization Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can do things like:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="Admins"/>
         <allow users="John" />
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the necessary security for the website, you could keep your accounts in memory as a dictionary perhaps. You could back it up with a hashed/salted/encrypted text file. When you have a change to your in-memory user list, you can serialize the object into text, encrypt it, hash/salt it, and store it to the text.